# Facebook share not working on wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have two WordPress sites that are hosted on the same server. The Facebook share is working on one website but it is not working on the other website.

Facebook share is working for http://gunnarkessler.com/
But it is not working for http://liebesfragen.com/

When debugging liebesfragen.com in Facebook debugger, it shows

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

The error message does not provide any useful information regarding the issue. How can I further debug this?

Thanks for your time. Please comment in case any other information is required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your website is not online yet. I'm getting the following error:

> liebesfragen.com
>
> Diese Webpräsenz befindet sich noch im Aufbau. Bitte versuchen Sie es
>   zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt noch einmal. This site is currently under
>   construction. Please try again later.

Is your site live? No regional restriction?

Can you check any IPv6 settings with your hosting company? Facebook uses IPv6 if the server indicates that it is supported. If I request your page over IPv4 I get a valid response, but we default to IPv6 if possible. It seems that your server replies it supports IPv6, but the request then actually fails.

Comment: Yes site is live and there are no regional restrictions. How are you checking it?

Comment: Just via internet. Have you whitelisted your own IP somewhere? Try to access the site using a free proxy service, see if you get the same result.

Comment: I have checked and the website is live. Also the problem is only in the Facebook share. The Google+ share is working fine.

Comment: Can you check any IPv6 settings with your hosting company? Facebook uses IPv6 if the server indicates that it is supported. If I request your page over IPv4 I get a valid response, but we default to IPv6 if possible.

It seems that your server replies it supports IPv6, but the request then actually fails.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. Please update your answer to include this so that I can mark it as accepted.